# Linux - Unable to remove directory that exist

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, rm

Tried to clean up `vim` bundle files today and ran into this directory hidden under one of the bundle that I simply cannot remove.

Ran `rm -rf` in directory `~/.vim/`, output as follow:

```
 ~/.vim/bundle $ rm -rf YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/testdata/
```

> rm: cannot remove ‘YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/testdata/’:Directory not empty

so I went into the directory to have a look:

```
 ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/testdata $ l
 total 12
 drwxrwxrwx 3 syan51 general 4096 Oct 11 17:44 .
 drwxrwxr-x 3 syan51 general 4096 Oct 11 17:44 ..
 drwx------ 2 syan51 general 4096 Oct 11 17:44 неприличное слово
```

then i try to remove this directory explicitly:

```
~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/testdata $ rm -r ./неприличное\ слово/
rm: remove directory ‘./неприличное слово/’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘./неприличное слово/’: No such file or directory
```

I tried `chmod`, `rm -ri -- *`, removing `testdata` instead, none worked. I tried `mv` and `cp`, both complaint that there is no such file or directory.

(Sidenote: anyone can kindly explain what the directory name means??)

Comment: what is the result of `whoami`?

Comment: find . -exec rm -rf {} \; ?

Comment: @Sundeep it just prints my username
@GeethanjaliEswaran `find: missing argument to `-exec'`

Answer (score 1):

Switch to root then try

```
rm -rf YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/testdata/
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am in a co-operate environment so do not have root access

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **strace rm -r ./неприличное\ слово/** to see what system call fails and what the error is, maybe it will help.

"неприличное слово" means "bad/rude word".